# Octave C++ feval "loglog" with octave_value_list

Tags: c++, octave

I have a function which should be evaluated with several inputs and I should analyze the output with loglog.

When I call feval("loglog", loglog_list) I get a seg fault :S

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/oct.h>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/octave.h>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/parse.h>

double f(double x) { return std::exp(std::sin(x)); }

int main() {
    string_vector argv (2);
    argv(0) = "embedded";
    argv(1) = "-q";
    octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec(), 1);

    octave_value_list loglog_arglist;

    for(int h = 0; h > -15; --h) loglog_arglist.append( octave_value( std::pow(10, h) ) );
    for(int h = 0; h > -15; --h) loglog_arglist.append( octave_value( f(std::pow(10, h)) ) );

    feval("loglog", loglog_arglist);
}
```

It should be a standalone application, which should draw a graph like octave does with

```
loglog (<x values>, <y values>)
```

I compile it with: mkoctfile --link-stand-alone -o out program.cpp